# Read the last console output and save it to a variable/string

Tags: java

I want to read the last output from the console and then save it to a variable.

Let's say I have this code and output:

```
System.out.println("first");
System.out.println("second");
System.out.println("third");
            ...
   **...THE CODE HERE...**
```

> first
>
> second
>
> third

Now I want it to read the last/latest output **from the console** and save it to a variable/string.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to do this ? What is the *purpose* ?

Comment: it's hard to explain

Answer (score 1):

The task is quite strange, but here's quick-and-dirty solution:

```
import java.io.FilterOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;


public class FilterOutput {
    static class MemorizingOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        String last = null;

        public MemorizingOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
            super(out);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            write(new byte[] {(byte)b}, 0, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            write(b, 0, b.length);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            out.write(b, off, len);
            String s = new String(b, off, len);
            int pos = s.lastIndexOf('\n');
            if(pos == -1) {
                sw.append(s);
            } else {
                int pos2 = s.lastIndexOf('\n', pos-1);
                if(pos2 == -1) {
                    sw.append(s.substring(0, pos));
                    last = sw.toString();
                } else {
                    last = s.substring(pos2+1, pos); 
                }
                sw = new StringWriter();
                sw.append(s.substring(pos+1));
            }
        }

        public String getLast() {
            return last;
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MemorizingOutputStream memOut = new MemorizingOutputStream(System.out);
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(memOut));

        System.out.println("first");
        System.out.println("second");
        System.out.println("third");

        System.err.println(memOut.getLast());
    }
}
```

First it replaces the standard output stream with special stream which memorizes the last string (assuming that strings end with `'\n'`). Then you can query that stream for the last string which was printed. Note that this implementation is not thread-safe.